# Create "batch" request using ExtJS 4.1 REST Proxy

Tags: json, rest, extjs, extjs4.1, batch-processing

I've got two model/proxy/stores I'm concerned with `Questions` and `Choices`. Both get data from a REST server as JSON. My process currently goes like this:

```
            // load numQuestions records from store.Questions
    var qs = Ext.getStore('Question');
            //... loadmask, etc.
    qs.load({
        scope : this,
        params : {
            limit : numQuestions
        },
        callback : function() {
            this.createQuestionCards(numQuestions);
        }
    });
```

Once I have the `Questions`, I loop through and fetch the `Choices` that are relevant to each `Question` like:

```
    for ( i = 0; i < numQuestions; i++) {
                // ... misc ...
        Assessor.questionChoices[i] = qs.getAt(i).choices();
                // ...misc...
        },
```

This works well, except that it makes an XMLHTTPRequest for every loop iteration. With minimum response times in the 0.15 sec area, that is fine for N < ~40. Once the numbers get to 200, which should be a common use case, the delay is nasty.

How do I get ExtJS to "batch" the requests and send them after the loop body? For example:

```
var choiceBatch = qs.createBatch();
for ( i = 0; i < numQuestions; i++) {
    // ... misc ...
    Assessor.questionChoices[i] = choiceBatch.getAt(i).choices();
    // ...misc...
};
choiceBatch.execute();
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4386701/extjs-restful-store-sending-request-in-batch?rq=1 seems to indicate that this does not work, however the answer is almost two years old.

Answer (score 0):

The *Ext.data.proxy.Rest* has a config option [batchActions](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.Rest-cfg-batchActions) and since it's [basically an AjaxProxy](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/source/Rest.html#Ext-data-proxy-Rest) with different methods it will probably work in the same way as the AjaxProxy.

Comment: I saw that `batchActions` parameter. Could you explain how to actually setup batch requests. There is no obvious way to so something like `var myBatch = myProxy.createBatch(); myBatch.getByID('adsf'); .... myBatch.execute();`

Comment: @justinzane try looking at the `batch()` method and the `batchOrder` property

Answer (score 0):

Since I am not getting clear answer about restful batch with multipart...

testing on my own with `batchActions=true` in `Ext.data.proxy.Rest` v4.2.1 result that batch is only within the same store and HTTP method. (`batchActions` default to false for the REST)

That means if there is 200 post & 1 delete and you call store.sync(), it will batch into 2 request, the POST request body will be wrapped with an array of records instead of single record.

I am looking for if it can batch all stores with all GET, POST, PUT and DELETE by using multipart/mixed **but the result is negative**. (check out [OData Batch Processing](http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-v2-documentation/batch-processing/))

Regarding the OP, what you looking for is the model associations. Once you create `Questions` and `Choices` Ext model and let the server respond with nested json data (So the `Questions` contain the child `Choices` embedded in a request) Ext will create `question` record along with `question.choices()` child store automatically.